# Individual task in composed task is not exiting

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

I used composed task runner to run two tasks. These two tasks refer to simple  spring boot applications. While launching the composed task, the first applications in the graph gets executed, but not exiting. Hence, the second application is not starting. If I configure both tasks to run in parallel, both the applications executes but doesn't exit.

Reference task : composed-task-runner --graph = task1 && task2

How do I make the tasks exit properly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the datasource. I was using different datasource for the server and spring cloud task. Once I specify the same datasource for everything, it worked

Comment: Can you please share how same data source for server and spring cloud task?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're doing in the custom Task applications. If you can edit the post and share the GitHub links to your applications, we can have a look. It'd be also good to review all the versions in use.

For a quick validation, though, you can use the out-of-the-box `timestamp` Task application. Build the same graph with this application and observe the behavior.

If you continue to see issues with the `timestamp` Task, it'd be a good idea to review the logs of the Server and as well as the Task applications.

Comment: I'm using simple spring boot apps which prints a message. I'm just trying to do a poc. I can see the printed message in the log. The log for the composed task runner shows that the first application is executed as a step. But it is not moving to the next step. The versions are same in all the applications. One more thing which I noticed is the start time of the individual tasks are not recorded. It is just showing as NA.

Comment: Task's in SCDF _should_ be a Spring Cloud Task application. It cannot just be a Spring Boot application. In other words, do you have `@EnableTask` annotation? Feel free to have a look at the [samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples) to get more clarity on the expectations.

Comment: If you do have an application correctly configured and you're continuing to see the reported behavior, please share a reproducable sample - a GitHub project link - we can review.

Comment: The issue is the datasource. I was using different datasource for the server and spring cloud task. Once I specify the same datasource for everything, it worked. Thanks